# An hour difference in a Microsoft Web Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, .net

All IIS logs on my server appear with and hour difference than what the server clock is set on.
In addition if I execute getdate() from my app the result will be again with an hour difference.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The date and the time stamp on entries in the IIS log files have an incorrect date and time stamp compared to the local time on the server.

This behaviour occurs because different log formats use different time zones for the basis of times listed in the logs. W3C Extended format which is default logging method, uses Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), basically the same as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). The other formats use local time. In short

`W3C` -  records the logs in `UTC`

`IIS` - records the logs in `local time`

`NCSA` - records the logs in `local time`

You can change the formats by selecting the site in IIS Manager then click the Logging icon in the right window pane.

For further reading please check [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525807(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)